# How do I use the prefix attribute selector in Less

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

In CSS you would use `div[class=^"btn-"]` but when I do this in Less I get the syntax error:

> SyntaxError: expected ']' got '^' in

How would I convert that CSS into Less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `^` in the wrong position, add the `^` before the equals `=` symbol.

```
div[class^="btn-"]
```

Using this in LESS would be the same as you would use it in CSS.